# Is it possible in android to read characters from web page

Tags: android

As this question doesnt relate to any problem but I want to develop an android  app for my website where if the user clicks on any article it will read and whole article and audio will start on click for that article .My question is it possible.In simple words I have to read characters on page and start audio for those character or words.

Comment: use text to speech! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can read web content if it's what you are asking.

You have a full android example here where the application connects to a url and download its content:

> Check link:

[How to read webpage contents as a string in Android?](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/17/how-to-read-webpage-contents-as-a-string-in-android/)

Once you have downloaded the web content you can use the "Text to Speech" engine to read it aloud:

> Check link:

[Android SDK: Using the Text to Speech Engine](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine/)